# How can I config puppeteer to get pdf page with full images and styles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

The images **- 2 -**  and some styles **- 1 -**  doesn't load when I use puppeteer `page.pdf.` Even if I set `page.waitForNavigation`.

[image]

If I use the same code with `page.screenshot` instead of `page.pdf` it works!

[image]

- Node v8.5.0
- Puppeteer 0.10.2(latest)

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );
const link = 'https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=pt-BR';
( async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(link);
  await page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 120000, waitUntil: 'networkidle', networkIdleTimeout: 3000});
  await page.pdf({path: 'page.pdf'});

  // if I remove page.pdf and change to the line below it works!
  //await page.screenshot({fullPage: true, path: 'page.png'});

  browser.close();
})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set printBackground param to true

```
await page.pdf( { path: 'test.pdf', printBackground: true } )
```